# How to assign a JSON string to a google pie chart data var

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-visualization

The problem I am facing is that in my web server I am sending a JSON as argument via render_template to my website where I want to use that JSON to show a google pie chart.

The problem is that if I assign the google pie chart data statically like this:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
  cols: [
    { id: "", label: "objeto", type: "string" },
    { id: "", label: "quantidade", type: "number" }
  ],
  rows: [
    { c: [{ v: "Caixa 2" }, { v: 3 }] },
    { c: [{ v: "Caixa 3" }, { v: 3 }] },
    { c: [{ v: "Caixa 4" }, { v: 3 }] }
  ]
});
```

It works perfectly. On the other hand if I assign it dynamically with the JSON that I am receiving from my server like this:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({{json}});
```

It stops showing the google pie chart in my website.

The things I tried until now was litteraly adapting the JSON to the desired format by google charts because I thought that was the only problem, but now that it is in the required format and it works statically I do not know any way of assigning my received JSON to the data var.

This is my ideal function that I would like to work.

```
function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({{json}});

  var options = {
    title: 'gráfico Objeto/Quantidade',
    is3D: true
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(
    document.getElementById('piechart')
  );
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Desired result:
http://prntscr.com/oejojv

Actual result:
http://prntscr.com/oejooe

Comment: Can you look at the page source and update your question with the parsed result of `var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({{json}});`? It's likely that the `json` value from the server is not being written into your JavaScript as you expect it to.

Comment: True, it is actually sending this:
{&#34;cols&#34;:[{&#34;id&#34;:&#34;&#34;,&#34;label&#34;:&#34;objeto&#34;,&#34;type&#34;:&#34;string&#34;},{&#34;id&#34;:&#34;&#34;,&#34;label&#34;:&#34;quantidade&#34;,&#34;type&#34;:&#34;number&#34;}],&#34;rows&#34;:[{&#34;c&#34;:[{&#34;v&#34;:&#34;Caixa 2&#34;},{&#34;v&#34;:3}]},{&#34;c&#34;:[{&#34;v&#34;:&#34;Caixa 3&#34;},{&#34;v&#34;:1}]},{&#34;c&#34;:[{&#34;v&#34;:&#34;Caixa 4&#34;},{&#34;v&#34;:2}]}]}

Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Ok I figured that the code &#34 is the ascii code for quotation marks, so now I have to find a way to change all the codes to actual quotation marks.

Comment: The JSON string is being HTML-escaped. Assuming that you're using Flask (guessing based on your mention of `render_template`), you need to do something like `{{json | safe}}`, but not 100% sure if that's all it takes. Also, this assumes that you have total control over the content of JSON, because you are otherwise susceptible to cross-site scripting attacks.

Comment: Omg it actually got fixed just by doing that! Thank you very much now I can keep on adding graphs :) I knew it couldn't be that complex!

Comment: Cool, I'll dupe my last comment for the answer 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON string is being HTML-escaped. Assuming that you're using Flask (guessing based on your mention of `render_template`), you need to do something like `{{json | safe}}`.

Also, this assumes that you have total control over the content of this JSON, because you are otherwise **susceptible to cross-site scripting attacks**.